# Django ORM and GROUP BY

Tags: django, django-models

Newcommer to Django here.

I'm currently trying to fetch some data from my model with a query that need would need a GROUP BY in SQL.

Here is my simplified model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    mmsi = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    point = models.PointField(geography=True)
```

I'm basically trying to get the last Message from every distinct mmsi number.

In SQL that would translates like this for example:

```
select a.* from core_message a
inner join
(select mmsi, max(time) as time from core_message group by mmsi) b
on a.mmsi=b.mmsi and a.time=b.time;
```

After some tries, I managed to have something working similarly with Django ORM:

```
>>> mf=Message.objects.values('mmsi').annotate(Max('time'))
>>> Message.objects.filter(mmsi__in=mf.values('mmsi'),time__in=mf.values('time__max'))
```

That works, but I find my Django solution quite clumsy. Not sure it's the proper way to do it.

Looking at the underlying query this looks like this :

```
>>> print(Message.objects.filter(mmsi__in=mf.values('mmsi'),time__in=mf.values('time__max')).query)
SELECT "core_message"."id", "core_message"."mmsi", "core_message"."time", "core_message"."point"::bytea FROM "core_message" WHERE ("core_message"."mmsi" IN (SELECT U0."mmsi" FROM "core_message" U0 GROUP BY U0."mmsi") AND "core_message"."time" IN (SELECT MAX(U0."time") AS "time__max" FROM "core_message" U0 GROUP BY U0."mmsi"))
```

I'd appreciate if you could propose a better solution for this problem.

Thanks !

Comment: How many messages & mmsi numbers are there in the dataset?

Comment: This is a subquery; Django has support for these, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions where the example is very similar to what you are doing.

Comment: I don't think the subquery will help here, since subquery would need to return a list, which `Subquery` doesn't do. Unfortunately, Django doesn't have a `group_by` feature that returns actual instances of the model. There is a [package django-group-by](https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by) that might be worth looking into.

Comment: @MaxMalysh potentially hundreds of thousands. The MMSI number is a special number used by every boat in the world and this database is aimed to be used for AIS, an open protocole to track boat near the coastlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answers and comments, I managed to solve this using a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) or a simple `distinct` `order by`.

**Simple `distinct` `order by` solution inspired by @Oriphiel answer:**

```
Message.objects.distinct('mmsi').order_by('mmsi','-time')
```

The underlying SQL query looks like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("core_message"."mmsi") "core_message"."id", "core_message"."mmsi", "core_message"."time", "core_message"."point"::bytea
FROM "core_message" 
ORDER BY "core_message"."mmsi" ASC, "core_message"."time" DESC
```

Simple and straightforward.

**Subquery solution inspired by @DanielRoseman comment:**

```
time_order=Message.objects.filter(mmsi=OuterRef('mmsi')).order_by('-time')
Message.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(time_order.values('id')[:1]))
```

The underlying SQL query looks like this :

```
SELECT "core_message"."id", "core_message"."mmsi", "core_message"."time", "core_message"."point"::bytea 
FROM "core_message" 
WHERE "core_message"."id" IN 
(SELECT U0."id" FROM "core_message" U0 WHERE U0."mmsi" = ("core_message"."mmsi") ORDER BY U0."time" DESC  LIMIT 1)
```

A tad more complex but it gives more flexibility. If I wanted to get first five messages for every MMSI, I'd just need to change the LIMIT value. In Django, it would look like this :

```
Message.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(time_order.values('id')[:5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need something like this:

```
Message.objects.all().distinct('mmsi').values('mmsi', 'time').order_by('mmsi','-id')
```

or like this:

```
Message.objects.all().values('mmsi').annotate(date_last=Max('time'))
```

Note: the last is translate by Django in this sql query:

```
SELECT "message"."mmsi", MAX("message"."time") AS "date_last" FROM "message" GROUP BY "message"."mmsi", "message"."time" ORDER BY "message"."time" DESC
```